# Filling a List in SwiftUI with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to fill a List with all entries from my "FlightRecording" entity. but I can't use `Text(recording.name)` because it says "NSManagedObject has no member 'name' ". 
Why is this even a NSManagedObject and not an object of type 'FlightRecordings' ?

```
struct FlightRecorderBrowser: View {
    let flightRecordings: [FlightRecording] = FlightRecorder().fetchAllRecordings()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List() {
                ForEach(flightRecordings, id: \.self) {recording in
                    Text(recording.name)
                }
            }

            .navigationBarTitle("Flight Recordings")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add an explicit type to the `ForEach` closure since a recording can be an `NSManagedObject` and a `FlightRecording` at the same time so the compiler just decided to use `NSManagedObject`.

```
ForEach(flightRecordings, id: \.self) { (recording: FlightRecording) in
    Text(recording.name)
}
```

Edit: If `recording.name` is optional you have to force-unwrap it or provide an alternative for Text to be able to use the value. `recording.name!` or `recording.name ?? "default-text"`

Another option to avoid errors on force-unwrap is to only show Text if `if recording.name != nil`.

Comment: Then I get a Compile Error for the ForEach line `Cannot convert value of type 'ForEach<[FlightRecording], FlightRecording, Text>' to closure result type '_'`

Comment: @nOk, just to clarify for others: you cannot pass the optional value to `Text`, so you need to unwrap it or pass the default one using the `??` operator. Unfortunately SwiftUI fails to provide a meaningful error message here, so it becomes a bit obscure.

Comment: been stuck on this for the past 2 hours or so. Swiftui max misleading errors, turns out it was just an optional string that needed to be force unwrapped -.-. Thanks, @nOk

Comment: They should definitely work on Xcode so that the error info actually appears at the error and not at a random bit of code before or after